# SQL query returns more rows than I need

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in SQL and I'm having trouble with a query that is supposed to return 3 rows but instead returns more than 300.

I'm doing a JOIN between 5 tables, like this

```
SELECT a.location, b.code, b.name, c.family, d.price, d.price + (1 * e.adjust /100)
FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
     JOIN c ON b.id=c.id
     JOIN d ON c.id=d.id
     LEFT JOIN e.id=c.id
WHERE b.code=31318
```

What am I missing?

Comment: One of your joins is doubling up rows. Take them out one by one to see which. If you want to aggregate you need `group by`

Comment: What does `select * from b where code=31318` return?

Comment: @Charlieface The problem is when I add E table, the option is hardcode the adjust but I can't do that because it can change

Comment: @Max It returns information about an item, but not the necessary enough to use less tables

Comment: "the option is hardcode the adjust" what?? Clearly, you have multiple matching rows in `e`. Maybe a "top 1 per group solution"?

Comment: What is the table definition of E? It sounds like `id` alone isn't a unique key.

Comment: If you run the following query,  and it returns only 3 rows, then add the next table and keep on adding till you see the number of rows more than expected. SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE b.code=31318

Comment: [mcve] makes it easier to assist.